# How to show the duration in the clip overlay in minutes and seconds instead of frames in Adobe Premiere Pro?

Tags: premiere

Even though my timeline is showing hours and minutes, when I hover over a clip I see the duration in frames. Is there a way to change this to hours and minutes?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out:

`Sequence | Sequence properties | Editing mode: HDV 720p | Display format: 29.97 fps Drop-Frame Timecode`